# Unknown icon on the status bar

Tags: applications

anyone can figure out what's the 2nd icon from the left ?[image]

Thanks

Comment: Left or right side? Remember, you can always pull down notification shade, and long press the notification to see what app it is

Comment: From the left side. It's not my phone. I'm just curious because i've never seen that icon before

Answer (score 3):

That icon is one of the apps from Opera Software and its called "Opera Max" thus the "M" icon and it is used for data saving or so it claims. Its shows you your estimated data usage and what you have saved. In their own words "Opera Max - Data Manager is a tool that lets you save considerably on the number of megabytes on your Android device's data plan using a simple procedure that automatically compresses all videos and images that you see (while using 3G) to around half their size. "

Hope your question is answered